# Why session service does not defined after refresh in ember while using torii

Tags: facebook, session, ember.js, torii

I'm using facebook login for my app. I am able to complete login successfully but when i refresh the page `session.isAuthenticate` becomes undefined.

I think the logic to persist the session stays inside fetch method of torii-adapter. Below is my torii-adapter and please tell me what is missing.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import {createToken} from 'myapp-new/utils/myapp-utils';
//import User from 'myapp-new/user/model';

export default Ember.Object.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service(),
  session: Ember.inject.service('session'),
  fetch(){
    let token = session.token;
    if(Ember.isEmpty(token)){
      throw new Error("No session found");
    }
    else{
      return Ember.RSVP.resolve({token});
    }
  },

  open: function(authentication){
    let authorizationCode = authentication.authorizationCode;
    let token = createToken();
    let adapter = this;
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      console.log(authentication);
      Ember.$.ajax({
        url: 'http://myapp.com/getUserInfoWuthAuthCode.php',
       //url:'http://localhost:4200',
        data: { 'code': authorizationCode,token:token},
        success: Ember.run.bind(null, resolve),
        error: Ember.run.bind(null, reject)
      });
    }).then(function(data){
      let user = data.user[0];

      return {
        token:token,
        user: user
      };
    });
  }
});
```

**UPDATE**
Below is code of my route

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    session: Ember.inject.service('session'),
    actions:{
        signIn(){
            console.log("Working");
            this.get('session').open('google-oauth2').then(function(){
                console.log("Login Worked");
            }, function(error){
                console.log('error', 'Could not sign you in: '+error.message);
            });
        }
    },
    setupController(controller, model){
        controller.set('session', this.session);
    }
});
```

I'm not using any component hence hooking session inside route only.
One thing to note about is fetch method of my torii-adapter is not getting called at all (it should be called on refresh, isn't it?)

Answer (score 1):

The Torii session variable should be set in the config file like this:

```
// config/environment.js
var ENV = {
  torii: {
  sessionServiceName: 'session'
}
```

This will inject the service variable to your routes among others. Also with each refresh of the app the session is closed, to avoid this use the beforeModel hook of your route, something like this:

```
beforeModel: function() {
  return this.get('session').fetch().catch(function() {});
},
```

Comment: using your code i am able to call my fetch method but not able to get my token from the session which i have assigned in my open method. i am able to get the token in my application using {{session.token}} but not after refresh as {{session.isAuthenticated}} becomes undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
let token = session.token;
```

This going to be always undefined (`session` object is undefined). The right way to do is,

```
let token = this.get('session.token')
// OR
this.get('session')['token']
```

I prefer the first option which looks more elegent, at least for me.

Comment: issue is not with the session code(it was wrong anyway, thanks for correcting). But in my component (hbs file) {{session.isAuthenticated}} is coming as undefined after refresh

Comment: Do you have `session` available inside `controller` at least the generated controller?

Comment: i have injected session in my route and just after login {{session.isAuthenticated}} evaluates to true, but not after refresh. On thing to notice about it is my fetch method of adapter doesn't gets called at all. May be i am missing something

Comment: No you have to make it available inside the controller (auto generated controller) by setting it up inside `setupController` hook.

Comment: i have used only application.hbs so i don't have any component in my app. Now I have hooked it in my route. below is code import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    session: Ember.inject.service('session'),
    actions:{
        signIn(){
            //signin code (working)
    },
    setupController(controller, model){
        controller.set('session', this.session);
    }
});
Is it correct? Or do you have any tutorial link to follow to get it working

Comment: Please update your question. I cannot see the code inside comments.

Comment: come on... this.session again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136730/discussion-between-kumar-gaurav-and-li-xinyang).

Answer (score 0):

@Falke's answer was helpful but wasn't solving my issue.

after some r&d i found the session.isAuthenticated was coming as undefined because my fetch method wasn't being called. Thanks to @falke i was able to get it run.

I stored my token in localstorage instead of session using below code in open method of my adapter

```
    open: function(authentication){
    let authorizationCode = authentication.authorizationCode;
    //let token = createToken();
   // let adapter = this;
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      console.log(authentication);   
      resolve({authorizationCode});
    }).then(function(data){      
      localStorage.setItem('token',authorizationCode);
      return {
        token:authorizationCode        
      };
    });
  }
```

I was able to find it back in my fetch method using code below

```
fetch(){
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    console.log(token);
    if(Ember.isEmpty(token)){
      throw new Error("No session found");
    }
    else{
      return Ember.RSVP.resolve({token});
    }
```

Hope this will help